# Laravel 4 - SortBy relation field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

These are the relevant models:

Task:

```
public function resolution() {
    return $this->hasOne('Resolution');
}
```

Resolution:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'task_id';
public $incrementing = false;

public function task() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Task');
}
```

So, I have the following code:

```
$tasks = Task::with(array(
    '... some relations ...'
))->whereHas('status', function($q) use($include) {
    $q->whereIn('slug', $include);
})->get()->sortByDesc(function($task) {
    return ($task->resolution->end ? $task->resolution->end : Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
});
```

This is returning exactly the collection of results that I want, with the correct ordering, but the ordering is happening **after** all the rows are retrieved.

What I need is to sort the results by the relation `resolution` (as shown above) **before** retrieving the data and then do a `->take(50)`, because there are going to be tens of thousands of rows coming from that table and the function is going to be hugely slow.

Is that possible with Eloquent? Because I don't want to have the code split between Eloquent and DB:Raw, which is a huge anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using sensible defaults for your table and column names, you can do:

```
$tasks = Task::with(array(
    '... some relations ...'
    ))
    ->whereHas('status', function($q) use($include) {
        $q->whereIn('slug', $include);
    })
    ->join('resolutions', 'tasks.id', '=', 'resolutions.task_id')
    ->orderBy('resolutions.end', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: prefix `id` to avoid ambiguity, and probably select only appropriate fields

Comment: lowerends it works nicely, although I've had to change some details specific to my case. That's a good general solution though. deczo is right, fields should be prefixed because of ambiguity. Thanks both.